# What is the part-of-speech of "intimates" in this article?

Tags: grammar, word-usage, parts-of-speech, contemporary-english

Commander Robert Broadhurst told MPs yesterday that there were "several **intimates**" from the Chinese that the London leg of the Olympic torch relay would have been switched to another capital city if Britain had banned their "torch attendants". (https://www.theguardian.com/world/2008/may/07/olympicgames2008.china)

I thought it couldn't be a verb, but for the noun I couldn't find a satisfactory definition in the OED.

Thank you in advance for the clarification!

Comment: It's a noun. And dictionaries are the last to know when a meaning changes.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 5):

It apparently means "intimations" (based on the context). I checked several dictionaries (both American and British) and couldn't find this meaning of "intimate" in any of them, so it seems to be a non-standard use of the word.

Comment: Google Books records at least hundreds of written instances of the sequence ***had intimations from***, but apparently the sequence ***had intimates from*** doesn't occur even *once* in [the entire 155 billion word corpus indexed by GB.](https://eadh.org/news/2011/05/13/google-books-corpus) I think we can safely say it was just a "slip of the tongue" by Commander Robert Broadhurst.

Comment: Thank you so much!